# SQL Returning count of common rows in a column with case when

Tags: mysql

I have this table where I can return a list of rows for a specific date range.
The row it is pulling from has a more data in it than I need so I've reduced that down using a case when

```
SELECT case when w.[description] like '%Provisioning%' then left (w.[description],charindex('Provisioning',w.[description])-2)
                                         else '' end as [Application]
FROM [Table 1] as w
left join [Table2] as i on i.[id] = w.[owner]
where [owner_name] in ('Specific_Owner')
and  (convert(datetime,dateadd(s,w.[created]/1000,'1970-01-01'),110) BETWEEN Convert(datetime, '2022-05-09' ) AND Convert(datetime, '2022-06-01' ))
and w.[description] not like '%Approve%'
```

Which gives an output as below:

| Application |
| --- |
| Application_A |
| Application_B |
| Application_A |
| Application_A |
| Application_A |
| Application_C |
| Application_C |

I would like to return a count of each application

So something like

| Application | Counts |
| --- | --- |
| Application_A | 4 |
| Application_B | 1 |
| Application_C | 2 |

Struggling a bit with this one! Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You can wrap your main query inside an outer query and do count(*) group by application - select  application, count( * ) from (your_big_query) t group by application;

Answer (score 0):

You add the group_by w.[description] and count(*) in select to get the exact result :

```
SELECT case when w.[description] like '%Provisioning%' then left (w.[description],charindex('Provisioning',w.[description])-2)
                                     else '' end as [Application],count(*)
FROM [Table 1] as w
left join [Table2] as i on i.[id] = w.[owner]
where [owner_name] in ('Specific_Owner')
and  (convert(datetime,dateadd(s,w.[created]/1000,'1970-01-01'),110) BETWEEN Convert(datetime, '2022-05-09' ) AND Convert(datetime, '2022-06-01' ))
and w.[description] not like '%Approve%'
group by w.[description];
```

Comment: Thanks for that.

The problem I have is that w.[description] is always unique for every row. I need to count by the alias [Application] which is not unique after the case query.

This solution gives me 

| Application    | Count |
| -------------- | ----- |
| Application_A  | 1     |
| Application_B  | 1     |
| Application_A  | 1     |
| Application_A  | 1     |
| Application_A  | 1     |
| Application_C  | 1     |
| Application_C  | 1     |

Comment: `GROUP BY 1` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use the case statement in group by like below and do a count(*)

```
SELECT case when w.[description] like '%Provisioning%' then left (w.[description],charindex('Provisioning',w.[description])-2)
                                         else '' end as [Application], count(*)
FROM [Table 1] as w
left join [Table2] as i on i.[id] = w.[owner]
where [owner_name] in ('Specific_Owner')
and  (convert(datetime,dateadd(s,w.[created]/1000,'1970-01-01'),110) BETWEEN Convert(datetime, '2022-05-09' ) AND Convert(datetime, '2022-06-01' ))
and w.[description] not like '%Approve%'
group by case when w.[description] like '%Provisioning%' then left (w.[description],charindex('Provisioning',w.[description])-2)
                                         else '' end
```